# Incorrect syntax near 'mainMenuNum'

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert

Here I am getting values of textbox which are created dynamically

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textboxValues = new List<string>();
    var textboxValues1 = new List<string>();

    if (Request.Form.HasKeys())
    {
        Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(i =>  i.Contains("Textbox")).ToList().ForEach(i => { textboxValues.Add(Request.Form[i]); });
        Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(j => j.Contains("Textbox1")).ToList().ForEach(j => { textboxValues1.Add(Request.Form[j]); });
    }

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IvrContext"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
```

Column data type is `nvarchar`. I can't figure out what the problem with this is; please help!

```
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO menudatas [mainMenuNum] values (@mainMenuNum)", conn);

    for(int x = 0; x<textboxValues.Count(); x++)
    { 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mainMenuNum", textboxValues[x]);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO menudatas [mainMenuText] values (@mainMenuText)" , conn);

    for (int y = 0; y < textboxValues1.Count(); y++)
    {  
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mainMenuText" , textboxValues1[y]);
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        container.Visible = false;
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you **keep adding** a parameter - with the same name every time - to your `SqlCommand`. You need to *define* the parameter **once**; before the loop - and then just assign the **value** to it in the loop:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO menudatas (mainMenuNum) values (@mainMenuNum)", conn);

// define your parameter ONCE before the loop
com.Parameters.Add("@mainMenuNum", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);   // adapt the datatype to match your situation

for(int x = 0; x<textboxValues.Count(); x++)
{ 
    // only assign the VALUE to the parameter repeatedly, in the loop
    com.Parameters["@mainMenuNum"].Value = textboxValues[x]);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO menudatas (mainMenuText) values (@mainMenuText)" , conn);

// define your parameter ONCE before the loop - and add it to the **correct** SqlCommand "com1" - not "com" ....
com1.Parameters.Add("@mainMenuText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  // adapt the datatype to match your situation

for (int y = 0; y < textboxValues1.Count(); y++)
{  
    // only assign the VALUE to the parameter repeatedly, in the loop
    com.Parameters["@mainMenuText"].Value = textboxValues1[y]);
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    container.Visible = false;
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: @ahmed: sorry, missed that - your SQL was wrong, you need to use round parenthesis `( .... )` around your column name in the `INSERT` statement - not square ones. Updated my response

Comment: i cant even imagine i did this mistake. Any way thanks for help